# Cell's formula not acting as a formula in excel?

Tags: vba, excel

I have set a cell's formula to equal a sum, yet the cell displays simply the equation, instead of the result of the equation... The value is not calculated, nor displayed. I can copy the contents of the formula from the cell and paste it into another one and that cell will display the result, but I need the initial one to display it. Here is the code:

```
Set SumRangeBegin = Cells(Sumrow, BeginSumColumn)
Set SumRangeEnd = Cells(Sumrow, EndSumColumn)
Set SumRangeTotal = Range(SumRangeBegin, SumRangeEnd)

ActiveCell.Formula = "=SUM(" & SumRangeTotal.Address & ")"
```

The cell will literally display =SUM($AA$854: $AV$854) (resulting from what I had set those variables to be initially... the SumRow and the SumColumn's), but won't display the result. Not sure why this is.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this -most probably cause is that the cell is set as text-

```
ActiveCell.NumberFormat = "General"
```

Answer (score 2):

Go to the Formulas menu in the Ribbon and see if Show Formulas is checked.

[image]